# onLocationChanged stop working in a Service when Activity is stoppped

Tags: android, location

I have a MainActivity that starts a MainService to log some positions with *GoogleApiClient*.

The *onLocationChanged* is in the Service (but I have another one in the MainActivy for a map).

When the activity is running, *onLocationChanged* is called normally. When the Activity is stopped, *onLocationChanged* is never called (but the Service is still running).

The Service is started with *startForeground* and *onStartCommand* returns *START_STICKY*;
.

Why does onLocationChanged stop being called?

EDIT: code

```
...
public class MainService extends Service implements
    LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My App")
            .setContentText("Working")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
    startForeground(42, notification);
    initGoogleApi();
    super.onCreate();
}

...

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((broadcastReceiver),
            new IntentFilter(Config.SERVICE_RESULT));
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void initGoogleApi(){
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(50F);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    startLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    doStuff(location);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    try {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //TODO
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("Service", "SERVICE IllegalStateException in startLocationUpdates");
    }
}
```

Comment: Will have to see code of service.  I made all this work in my app by having the service do onLocationChanged and logging the results.  The service saves locations in data provider.  The app uses same data provider to get locations.  This way when the app shuts down the service can still be logging locations

Comment: @danny117 code posted. I hope you will find some differences with yours